# ¿como hago para hacer un update desde react a postgres usando un dni?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, postgresql, express

estoy intentando actualizar una lista de clientes el cual tiene como primary key su dni a la hora de intentar actualizar dicho registro me salta un error 500 de que no me esta reconociendo el dni que le mando he probado varias cosas pero nada. por favor si me pueden echar una mano

este es el error (Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/clientes/41232516J' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
PUT http://localhost:3001/clientes/41232516J net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch)

este es el index.js que esta en el backend

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

const cliente_model = require('./clientes')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers')
    next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    cliente_model.getClientes()
    .then(response => {
        res.status(200).send(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    })
})

app.post('/clientes', (req, res) => {
    cliente_model.setClientes(req.body)
         .then(response => {
             res.status(200).send(response)
          })
         .catch(error => {
             res.status(500).send(error)
          })
})

app.put('/clientes/:dni', (req, res) => {
    cliente_model.updateClientes(req.params.dni, req.body)
       .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(response)
        })
       .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log('puerto: ' + port)
})
```

y aquí esta el método de app.js del frontend el cual le manda en teoría el dni al index

```
updateClientes = () => {
var dni = this.state.dni
var nombre = this.state.nombre
var apellidos = this.state.apellidos
var telefono = this.state.telefono
var codigoP = this.state.codigo_postal
fetch('http://localhost:3001/clientes/'+dni, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: JSON.stringify({ nombre, apellidos, telefono, codigoP }),
})
  .then(response => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(data => {
    this.getClientes()
  })
this.cerrarPopUp()
this.setState({
  dni: '',
  nombre: '',
  apellidos: '',
  telefono: '',
  codigo_postal: '',
})
}
```

y este es el que uso de insertar que si funciona

```
insertClinetes = () => {
var dni = this.state.dni
var nombre = this.state.nombre
var apellidos = this.state.apellidos
var telefono = this.state.telefono
var codigoP = this.state.codigo_postal
fetch('http://localhost:3001/clientes', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ dni, nombre, apellidos, telefono, codigoP }),
})
  .then(response => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(data => {

    this.getClientes()
  })
this.cerrarPopUp()
this.setState({
  dni: '',
  nombre: '',
  apellidos: '',
  telefono: '',
  codigo_postal: '',
})
}
```

y el de mostrar

```
getClientes = () => {
fetch('http://localhost:3001')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      clientes: data,
    })
  })
 }
```

datos de prueba(dni:'12345678M',nombre:'inventado',apellidos:'inventado',telefono:'987654321', codigoP:'12345' )

he estado buscando ejemplos con strings pero solo encuentro con numéricos pero esos ejemplos no me valen

Comment: Hola, Bill. Felicidades por esas vacunas y lamento tu divorcio :P Por favor, pon el mensaje de error completo en tu pregunta, no sólo un resumen. Y lo otro, incluye el model donde está getclientes para ver qué puede estar fallando (de paso, datos de prueba porque ni idea cómo es un dni, vivo en Colombia y acá no hay de eso)

Comment: ok dame unos minutos

Comment: ya esta modificado y tienes al final unos datos de prueba

Comment: El error indica que el CORS está bloqueando el acceso. Intenta instalando cors (npm install cors). Puede que esté link te ayude https://fullstackopen.com/es/part3/implementacion_de_la_aplicacion_en_internet

Comment: acabo de hacer unos console.log  y veo que estoy recibiendo todos los datos pero no me hace la consulta sql la probé en la base de datos y si la hace pero en el código no

Comment: ya conseguí arreglar lo del update el error era que nome cogia bien la sentencia al estar repara por los + se los quite y me funciona. gracias de todos modos @davidbug